# Is it possible to use clusters in clusters with orientdb?

Tags: database, graph, orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

I was going through the OrientDB tutorial yesterday and think it looked really promising.

I like the possibility to add entities to different [clusters](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Clusters.html) and my question is if it is possible to have a hierarchy of clusters?

As an example, if I add a `User` to the cluster `California` I would like it to also be a part of the cluster `USA` without having to specifically add it to that cluster.

I am thinking about clusters as a way to divide data in sets and subsets, but maybe that is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `Classes` are. You have real inheritance between classes, so querying a base class will give you all the instances of that class and its subclasses.

Clusters are a more physical concepts, think to them like a file or a table. A Class uses one or more clusters to store instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In my example I would make `California` and `Washington` subclasses of `USA` even if they have the exact same properties?

Comment: Yes, they inherit all the properties from USA